# How do I write higher-order functions that take polymorphic functions as arguments in Typed Racket?

Tags: types, racket, higher-order-functions, typed-racket, polymorphic-functions

For example, how can I write a version of `map` that will work with polymorphic functions in Typed Racket? I use a simple `id` function defined as:

```
(: id : (All (A) A -> A))
(define (id x) x)
```

When I try to map it over a list i get an error:

```
> (map id '(1 2 3))

Type Checker: Polymorphic function `map' could not be applied to arguments:
Types: (-> a b ... b c) (Listof a) (Listof b) ... b -> (Listof c)
   (-> a c) (Pairof a (Listof a)) -> (Pairof c (Listof c))
Arguments: (All (A) (-> A A)) (List One Positive-Byte Positive-Byte)
Expected result: AnyValues
   in: (map id (quote (1 2 3)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to manually instantiate the polymorphism in this case:

```
->  (map (inst identity Integer) '(1 2 3))
- : (Listof Integer) [more precisely: (Pairof Integer (Listof Integer))]
'(1 2 3)
```

The reason is explained in the Typed Racket Guide [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/caveats.html#%28part._.Type_inference_for_polymorphic_functions%29):

> Typed Racket’s local type inference algorithm is currently not able to
>   infer types for polymorphic functions that are used on higher-order
>   arguments that are themselves polymorphic.

(see docs for more explanation and examples)