# Understanding typechecker behavior around `case->`

Tags: racket, typed-racket

On the REPL, this is what I get when I inspect type of `car`

```
> car
- : (All (a b) (case-> (-> (Pairof a b) a) (-> (Listof a) a)))
```

It returns an element of first type in a pair when passed a pair where the second value may not exist.

Now I would like to use it in a function which maps over list of pairs and gets the first element

```
(: f (-> (Listof (Pairof Integer Symbol)) (Listof Integer))
```

When I try writing my function like the following, typechecking fails

```
(define (f l) (map car l))
; stdin::9317: Type Checker: Polymorphic function `map' could not be applied to arguments:
; Types: (-> a c) (Pairof a (Listof a)) -> (Pairof c (Listof c))
;        (-> a b ... b c) (Listof a) (Listof b) ... b -> (Listof c)
; Arguments: (All (a b) (case-> (-> (Pairof a b) a) (-> (Listof a) a))) (Listof (Pairof Integer Symbol))
; Expected result: (Listof Integer)
; 
;   in: (map car l)
```

However, if I wrap the car function in a lambda which has the effect of specifying the input type to `car`, then my implementation type-checks perfectly

```
(define (f l) (map (lambda ([x : (Pairof Integer Symbol)]) (car x)) l))
```

What's exactly going on here and why isn't the typechecker smart enough to infer from the function argument's type annotation that it should use the first of the two cases in the `car` function?

Comment: See [How do I write higher-order functions that take polymorphic functions as arguments in Typed Racket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212222/how-do-i-write-higher-order-functions-that-take-polymorphic-functions-as-argumen)